# Comparing 2 distinct sieve of Eratosthenes algorithms in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, comparative-review, sieve-of-eratosthenes

In this post, I will present and compare two distinct algorithms for sieve of Eratosthenes:

**`com.github.coderodde.math.prime.PrimeFinder`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.math.prime;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This abstract defines the API for finding prime numbers.
 * 
 * @author Rodin "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 12, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 12, 2021)
 */
public abstract class PrimeFinder {
    
    /**
     * Finds all the primes no larger than {@code limit} and returns them in a 
     * sorted list.
     * 
     * @param limit the maximum allowed prime.
     * @return a list of primes.
     */
    public abstract BitSet findPrimesUpTo(int limit);
    
    /**
     * Converts all the primes in {@code bitSet} to the list.
     * 
     * @param bitSet the target bit set describing the primes.
     * @param numberOfBits the number of actual numbers in {@code bitSet}.
     * @return the prime list.
     */
    public static List<Integer> 
        primeBitSetToList(
                BitSet bitSet,
                int numberOfBits) {
            
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(bitSet.size());
        
        for (int i = 0; i < bitSet.size(); i++) {
            if (bitSet.get(i)) {
                list.add(i);
            }
        }
        
        return list;
    }
    
    protected void checkLimit(int limit) {
        if (limit < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative limit: " + limit);
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.math.prime.impl.LinearithmicPrimeFinder`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.math.prime.impl;

import com.github.coderodde.math.prime.PrimeFinder;
import java.util.BitSet;

/**
 * This class implements the basic sieve of Eratosthenes running in 
 * {@code O(n log n)} time.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 12, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 12, 2021)
 */
public final class LinearithmicPrimeFinder extends PrimeFinder {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public BitSet findPrimesUpTo(int limit) {
        checkLimit(limit);
        
        if (limit < 2) {
            return new BitSet(limit);
        }
        
        if (limit == 2) {
            BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(3);
            bitSet.set(2);
            return bitSet;
        }
        
        BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(limit + 1);
        bitSet.set(0, bitSet.size(), true);
        bitSet.clear(0);
        bitSet.clear(1);
        
        // Deal with powers of two:
        for (int i = 4; i <= limit; i += 2) {
            bitSet.set(i, false);
        }
        
        // Deal with powers of odd primes:
        for (int primeCandidate = 3;
                primeCandidate <= limit; 
                primeCandidate += 2) {
            if (bitSet.get(primeCandidate)) {
                for (int i = 2 * primeCandidate; 
                        i <= limit; 
                        i += primeCandidate) {
                    bitSet.set(i, false);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return bitSet;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.math.prime.impl.FasterPrimeFinder`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.math.prime.impl;

import com.github.coderodde.math.prime.PrimeFinder;
import java.util.BitSet;

/**
 * This class implements a sieve of Eratosthenes prime finder described in
 * <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Pseudocode">
 * Wikipedia</a>. Runs in {@code O(n log log n)} time.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 12, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 12, 2021)
 */
public final class FasterPrimeFinder extends PrimeFinder {

    @Override
    public BitSet findPrimesUpTo(int limit) {
        checkLimit(limit);
        
        if (limit < 2) {
            return new BitSet(limit);
        }
        
        if (limit == 2) {
            BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(3);
            bitSet.set(2);
            return bitSet;
        }
        
        BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(limit + 1);
        bitSet.set(0, bitSet.size(), true);
        bitSet.clear(0);
        bitSet.clear(1);
        
        for (int i = 2, end = (int)(Math.sqrt(limit)) + 1; i < end; i++) {
            if (bitSet.get(i)) {
                for (int j = i * i; j <= limit; j += i) {
                    bitSet.clear(j);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return bitSet;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.math.prime.Demo`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.math.prime;

import com.github.coderodde.math.prime.impl.FasterPrimeFinder;
import com.github.coderodde.math.prime.impl.LinearithmicPrimeFinder;
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.List;

public final class Demo {

    private static final int MAX_PRIME = 300_000_000;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrimeFinder primeFinder1 = new LinearithmicPrimeFinder();
        PrimeFinder primeFinder2 = new FasterPrimeFinder();
        
        List<Integer> list1 = getPrimeList(MAX_PRIME, primeFinder1);
        List<Integer> list2 = getPrimeList(MAX_PRIME, primeFinder2);
        
        System.out.println("Agreed: " + list1.equals(list2));
    }
    
    private static List<Integer> getPrimeList(int limit, PrimeFinder finder) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        BitSet primeSieve = finder.findPrimesUpTo(limit);
        
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration = endTime - startTime;
        
        System.out.println(
                finder.getClass().getSimpleName() + " in " + duration + 
                        " milliseconds.");
    
        List<Integer> list = 
                PrimeFinder.primeBitSetToList(primeSieve, limit + 1);
        
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind. Especially, I am concerned with class and method naming.

Comment: (While the title is spot-on, I don't think you *wish to know which of the solutions you presented is best (and why)*.)

Comment: Does Java Bitset not have a find-next-set interface?  You really have to query bits one at a time?  If the actual implementation is a bit-array / bitmap, searching for next set could be much faster if there was an API for it.  I checked, there is an API: [`nextSetBit(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextSetBit(int))

Comment: @PeterCordes I checked half a day earlier - don't expect "the candidate check" to take a significant part of the time, and don't expect significant improvement given the average gap. Any benchmarkers?

Comment: @greybeard: Yeah, that conversion is cheap compared to sieving, but it could still be improved, especially since it's a separately reusable function.  Also approximating the number of primes <= n to avoid over-allocating a huge ArrayList is not a bad idea.  I added an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just a few stabs:

- Why an `abstract class`? You could even have static method members in `interface`s.
- `/* Finds all the primes no larger than {@code limit} and returns them in a * sorted list.` I read `BitSet findPrimesUpTo(int limit)`
- `PrimeFinder.primeBitSetToList()` - what is the relation to primes?
  Why convert in the first place?
  Why not to `Set<>`?
- While `PrimeFinder` does look the place for `checkLimit()`, it does not seem the proper place for *other stuff shared by sieves*. The two presented deserve one.
- `bitSet.set(2, bitSet.size());` ((version 1.6:) did you convert from an implementation in a different language?)
- `// Deal with powers of two:` I read *multiples*?!
- `end = (int)(Math.sqrt(limit))` shouldn't *floor* be sufficient?
- I'm struggling with "the main loop" - no special casing 2, "no" checking of even numbers.
  Might be less cumbersome in a generic wheel implementation.

  - I'm doubtful of termination with `limit` near `Integer.MAX_VALUE`
    (Doesn't even reach "the loops" with 1.8, but fails when trying to set a range up to -2^31 - the return value of `.size()`. And fails for negative `j += i` after circumventing this `util.BitSet` peculiarity.)
    Suggestion: document to work up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2 * Character.MAX_VALUE - 2`, update `checkLimit()` accordingly.

  Currently at

  ```
  final int end = (int)(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(limit))) + 1; // limit for Basic?
  for (int i = 2, inc = 1; i < end; i += inc, inc = 2)
  ```

  Alternatively, drop `end` at the cost of legibility:

  ```
    for (int i = 2, inc = 1 ; ; i += inc, inc = 2)
        if (pPrimes.get(i)) {
            int j = i * i;
            if (limit < j)
                return pPrimes;
            do {
                pPrimes.clear(j);
                j += i+i;  // *full* map *is* kind of weird 
            } while (j <= limit);  // && 0 < j?
        }
  ```

*Naming* is important - and difficult. With derivation/`extends`, I'd rather not repeat the base name. With `implements`, I'm not so sure.
I think I'd go for `BasicEratosthenes`.
(I have no misgivings whatsoever with the names `Demo` and `main()`.
`getPrimeList()` does more than to expect from its name. (`handle…()` is *lame*.))
(for comparison:)

```
        // Deal with odd multiples of odd primes:
        for (int primeCandidate = 3;
                primeCandidate <= limit; 
                primeCandidate += 2) {
            if (pPrimes.get(primeCandidate)) {
                for (int prime2 = primeCandidate * 2,
                     i = primeCandidate * 3;  // not fixable with 0 <= i &&
                        i <= limit; 
                        i += prime2) {
                    pPrimes.set(i, false);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't a significant portion of the *total* time including sieving, but converting a bitset to an array / ArrayList of integers can be done more efficiently by **searching for the next set bit** with [`i = bitset.nextSetBit(i);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextSetBit(int)), rather than querying every bit separately.  (It returns `-1` for not found.)

It may avoid branch mispredicts when the next set bit is in the same machine word of the underlying bitmap, hopefully taking advantage of machine instructions that scan an integer for the lowest set bit (after right-shifting or masking to remove the bits below the start position in this integer chunk of the bitmap).

It may well be slower when set bits are close together, but once you get to reasonable sizes and primes get farther apart, a fast search for the next set bit is hopefully good.  For large distances, you'd expect a good implementation to be checking at least 64 bits at a time to see if they contain a non-zero bit, only then bit-scanning within that integer.

---

#### Size your allocation to the expected number of primes `<= n`

```
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(bitSet.size());
```

**That's a significant over-allocation.**  The exact size is `bitSet.cardinality()`, but that would have to popcount your bitset.  Instead probably better to slightly over-estimate and then trim the array.  The number of primes <= n can be approximated as `n / log(n)`, which under-estimates by 11% for n=10^4, or by 5% for n=10^9.

```
  // This is an over-estimate for large n, maybe an under-estimate for small n.
  // ArrayList can grow if needed, and that's cheap for small a ArrayList.
  int approxPrimeCount = (int)(bitSet.size() * 1.10 / Math.log(bitSet.size()));
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(approxPrimeCount + 20);
  // fixed + 20 to make sure it's sane at small size, and we can use a smaller scale factor
```

(If your bitset only represents odd numbers, it's about twice as dense, so multiply by 2.2 instead of 1.1)

In terms of space savings, for n=10^9, you'd allocate space for 1 billion ints (4 GB ~= 3.72 GiB).  But exact Pi(10^9) = 50,847,534, so you only need space for ~51M.  (195 MiB).  That's 19.67 times as much space needed for the naive allocation.  (ln(1e9) = 20.7).  My over-estimation approximation gives `53080436 + 20` elements, taking 202.4 MiB of space, still a factor of 18.8 vs. the size of the naive allocation.

So that's huge, unless elements of an ArrayList you only reserve capacity for but don't touch are cheap.  (e.g. if the implementation doesn't zero them, so any fresh pages it got from the OS remain untouched, never page-faulted.)

**Or instead of calling `log`**, use `31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros( size )` as [an approximation for integer log2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305059/how-do-you-calculate-log-base-2-in-java-for-integers).  If over-estimating the space required is not costly (e.g. if we can resize the ArrayList to just the used space after filling it), we can do `n / ilog2(n) * 3 / 2 + 20` or something.  Dividing by log2(n) instead of ln(n) will give smaller results, so we're rolling that into our scale factor with `3/2` as a quick hack.  ilog2 will over estimate for numbers that aren't powers of 2, e.g. log2(255) is 7.994, but ilog2(255) = 7.

Or log2(10^9) ~= 29.89, so ilog2(10^9) is 29.  That rounding down in the divisor can lead to a fairly large over-allocation in absolute terms, but being fast for small N can be worth it.

---

**When you're done, you can trim the ArrayList capacity to its size with `.trimToSize()`**, giving back any reserved space you didn't end up needing.  Unless of course you expect to be appending more numbers later.

---

In your loop limit calculation, **there's a lot going on in one line.**

```
// FasterPrimeFinder
        for (int i = 2, end = (int)(Math.sqrt(limit)) + 1; i < end; i++) {
          ...
        }
```

I think it would be preferable to have `int end = ...` *outside* the for loop, even though that means it's still in scope after the loop.  This is inside a relatively small function so it's fine.  I find it easier to see the simple idiomatic loop structure after pulling the big `end` expression out of it.

```
        int end = (int)(Math.sqrt(limit)) + 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < end; i++) {
          ...
        }
```

---

Also, `2` is the only even prime, so you can just factor that out of the outer loop and do `i+=2;`.  You do that in `LinearithmicPrimeFinder`, but not in `FasterPrimeFinder`, which leaves me wondering, "faster than what"?  It isn't *totally* naive, for example calculating loop limits, and starting at `i*i`.

Or better, **don't even store even numbers in your bitset**, so `bitset[i]` actually represents `i*2+3`, or odd integer `j` is represented by `bitset[ (j-3)>>1 ]`.  Neither of your implementations do that.

Even multiples of primes don't need to be marked off, you're already implicitly ignoring them.  So you can still use `idx += i` to iterate through the odd multiples to mark them off, I think.  (This does require some care to get the logic right, like the squaring for where to start needs to use the integer, not the bit-index.)

This can even be generalized to a "wheel" of implicitly skipping multiples of 3 and 5 as well, but that's more complicated.  Skipping even numbers is pretty much pure win.  This is described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Overview

Comment: (*just factor [checking even numbers for primality] out of the outer loop and do `i+=2;`*: coderodde does in `LinearithmicPrimeFinder.findPrimesUpTo()`.)

Comment: (Note that *next special bit* couldn't just be used in converting result set representation: It looks a valid alternative to using a wheel.)

Comment: @greybeard: Good point, I did notice that, but forgot to specify that I was talking about the "FasterPrimeFinder" which doesn't.  Re: a wheel: I think a big part of the reason for using a wheel is to save space, and memory / cache bandwidth when striding through marking off multiples.  And also bit set/clear operations.  Iterating over the bitmap at the end isn't the primary motivation for making it denser with a wheel.  (But I forget exactly how the wheel algorithm works, and what extra costs it entails.)

Comment: Of course, the cache footprint problem can be addressed by cache-blocking, which apparently is possible with a [segmented sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Segmented_sieve), so you can get mostly L2 cache hits I guess.

Answer (score 2):

### Class naming

The names you used are fine IMO. You could prefix `PrimeFinder` with `Abstract`, but that's personal preference. Even Java's builtin classes aren't consistent with it (see `Reader` vs. `AbstractSet<E>`, both are abstract).
I've also seen the `Base` suffix (e.g. `PrimeFinderBase`), but not very often.

### Method naming

`findPrimesUpTo()` could be shortened to `findPrimes()`. Any IDE should show you the signature on hover or while typing AND there's a javadoc comment describing the parameter (also displayed by the IDE).

Adding to that, there are methods like `Random.nextInt()` and `String.substring()`. Changing the method names to explain the arguments only adds length to the name while not giving any further information:

```
Random.nextIntSmallerThan(int bound);
Random.nextInt(int bound); // actual method

String.substringBetween(int start, int end);
String.substring(int start, int end); // actual method

PrimeFinder.findPrimesUpTo(int limit);
PrimeFinder.findPrimes(int limit); // ???
```

<del>There may be cases where choosing the longer name is better, but I'd argue against it in this case.</del>

UPDATE: See comments on further arguments pro/con shortening.

### Static

Both classes should only have static methods. They're a collection of methods for a purpose, a service provider, which doesn't need to be instatiated. Currently, you create an object every time you want to find primes, which is weird to read, weird to write/use and possibly bad for performance.

Comment: `[The classes are something] which doesn't need to be [instantiated]` have a look at `Demo.getPrimeList()`

Comment: "*`findPrimesUpTo()` should be shortened to `findPrimes()`.*" I disagree. Code like `findPrimesUpTo(42)`  is clear and self-documenting, whereas the meaning of the argument in `findPrimes(42)` is completely obscure if you see it outside the IDE (like, say, in a Stack Exchange post).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm undecided. With "naked code", I prefer "reads unequivocally". Using an IDE, I prefer short names and useful pop-ups on "mouse" hovers like `BitSet findPrimes(int upToIncluding);` - with useful interpretation of, say, *doc comments* I might move `Including` there (if free to modify the interface, I'm leaning towards `Object findPrimes(int below, util.Collection accumulator);`(& 1-parameter overload).) (Every now&then, I wish I knew English.)

Comment: Concerning the shortening if `findPrimesUpTo`, I was undecided if I should write *should* or *could*. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to give my two cents about a very small optimization that everybody oversees.

You're developing a `FastErathostenes`, but you have the following code:

```
        checkLimit(limit);
        
        if (limit < 2) {
            return new BitSet(limit);
        }
        
        if (limit == 2) {
            BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(3);
            bitSet.set(2);
            return bitSet;
        }
```

If one wants to optimize, they'll think that limit will rarely be below 2. So we actually perform 3 times the same checks on the same value for most of the cases. So instead move the triple check to where it's the most likely to be less costly.

I suggest instead the following code:

```
        if (limit <= 2) {
            if (limit < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative limit: " + limit);
            }
            BitSet primes = new BitSet();
            if (limit == 2) {
                primes.set(2);
            }
            return primes;
        }
```

When given no size or `nbits` between 0 and 63, `BitSet` will always create an array of at least one element. It doesn't say so on the Javadoc, but the implementation is rather clear about it. So there's no need to make a distinction between the constructors if you know that you'll never store any value above 63.

Answer (score 0):

One can split hairs over naming until the cows come home. And at the end of the day, someone will always disagree anyway. As long as it's not horrid, you're good. Your code will work and do the thing.

What's more important is the API that you present to your users.

In this case you have chosen to create an extensible class hierarchy. This is OK, but your choice of interface methods leaks implementation details. In particular your base class assumed every prime finder will be of a sieve type and use a bit set to return it's results. These choices are limiting you to this class of solution. The API should allow you to implement a prime finder with trial division if you want, or to load a long list of primes from disk. Both of these become clonky to convert first to bit set and then back to a list.

I would recommend changing the API so that it returns the list of integers directly and possibly offer a helper function to convert from bit list to list of integers.